# Mongodb 3.2.1 database stopped working cent os 7

Tags: mongodb, centos7

I am running mongodb 3.2.1 in the centos7 server.  It was working fine but it stopped working.

```
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# sudo service mongod start
Starting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed because the cont                                                  rol process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "j                                                  ournalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]

[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# systemctl status mongod.service
● mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-03-01 15:21:33 UTC; 28s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2308 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 01 15:21:33 CentOS-73-64-minimal systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database....
Mar 01 15:21:33 CentOS-73-64-minimal mongod[2308]: Error starting mongod. /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid exists.
Mar 01 15:21:33 CentOS-73-64-minimal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 01 15:21:33 CentOS-73-64-minimal systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
Mar 01 15:21:33 CentOS-73-64-minimal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Mar 01 15:21:33 CentOS-73-64-minimal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# journalctl -xe"
> ^C
```

Then i /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid deleted and start the service again but same issue.

```
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# sudo rm /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# sudo service mongod start
Starting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl
                                                           [FAILED]

[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# systemctl status mongod.service
● mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-03-01 15:30:01 UTC; 10s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2373 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 01 15:30:01 CentOS-73-64-minimal systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database....
Mar 01 15:30:01 CentOS-73-64-minimal runuser[2380]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by (uid=0)
Mar 01 15:30:01 CentOS-73-64-minimal runuser[2380]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user mongod
Mar 01 15:30:01 CentOS-73-64-minimal mongod[2373]: Starting mongod: [FAILED]
Mar 01 15:30:01 CentOS-73-64-minimal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 01 15:30:01 CentOS-73-64-minimal systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
Mar 01 15:30:01 CentOS-73-64-minimal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Mar 01 15:30:01 CentOS-73-64-minimal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# journalctl -xe"
> ^C
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# ^C
```

## mongod output

```
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# mongod
2017-03-01T15:53:36.694+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2472 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=CentOS-73-64-minimal
2017-03-01T15:53:36.694+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.12
2017-03-01T15:53:36.694+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ef3e1bc78e997f0d9f22f45aeb1d8e3b6ac14a14
2017-03-01T15:53:36.694+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2017-03-01T15:53:36.694+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-03-01T15:53:36.694+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-03-01T15:53:36.694+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-03-01T15:53:36.694+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2017-03-01T15:53:36.694+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-03-01T15:53:36.694+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-03-01T15:53:36.694+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-03-01T15:53:36.761+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-03-01T15:53:36.761+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=18G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-03-01T15:53:39.753+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2017-03-01T15:53:39.753+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-03-01T15:53:39.754+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2017-03-01T15:53:39.754+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-03-01T15:53:39.923+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

I tried in many ways by searching google but no success. please help me on it. Thanks in advance

## mongod.log

```
2017-03-01T15:30:01.279+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2017-03-01T15:30:01.284+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2384 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=CentOS-73-64-minimal
2017-03-01T15:30:01.284+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.12
2017-03-01T15:30:01.284+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ef3e1bc78e997f0d9f22f45aeb1d8e3b6ac14a14
2017-03-01T15:30:01.284+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2017-03-01T15:30:01.284+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-03-01T15:30:01.284+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-03-01T15:30:01.284+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-03-01T15:30:01.284+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2017-03-01T15:30:01.284+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-03-01T15:30:01.284+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-03-01T15:30:01.284+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2017-03-01T15:30:01.300+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongo created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-03-01T15:30:01.300+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=18G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-03-01T15:30:01.304+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (0) [1488382201:304893][2384:0x7fcff0fb9dc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: read checksum error for 4096B block at offset 49152: block header checksum of 3921565147 doesn't match expected checksum of 3944682197
2017-03-01T15:30:01.304+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (0) [1488382201:304939][2384:0x7fcff0fb9dc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: WiredTiger.wt: encountered an illegal file format or internal value
2017-03-01T15:30:01.304+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (-31804) [1488382201:304948][2384:0x7fcff0fb9dc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2017-03-01T15:30:01.304+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28558
2017-03-01T15:30:01.304+0000 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


2017-03-01T15:30:01.316+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x132c032 0x132b189 0x132b992 0x7fcfefc21370 0x7fcfef8861d7 0x7fcfef8878c8 0x12b2312 0x10ac2a3 0x96a1e5 0x96a2ba 0x96a47e 0x19c00dc 0x19c0643 0x19bcfc9 0x19c18c9 0x19de134 0x1a158cb 0x1a9e0ce 0x1a9e755 0x1a9ebcb 0x1a24456 0x1a942dd 0x1a5fa4f 0x1a5fb5e 0x1a11d2e 0x109373f 0x108f9f3 0xfb86c8 0x9b2a4e 0x9b4fc0 0x96adbd 0x7fcfef872b35 0x9af377
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"F2C032","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"400000","o":"F2B189"},{"b":"400000","o":"F2B992"},{"b":"7FCFEFC12000","o":"F370"},{"b":"7FCFEF851000","o":"351D7","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7FCFEF851000","o":"368C8","s":"abort"},{"b":"400000","o":"EB2312","s":"_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi"},{"b":"400000","o":"CAC2A3"},{"b":"400000","o":"56A1E5"},{"b":"400000","o":"56A2BA","s":"__wt_err"},{"b":"400000","o":"56A47E","s":"__wt_panic"},{"b":"400000","o":"15C00DC"},{"b":"400000","o":"15C0643"},{"b":"400000","o":"15BCFC9"},{"b":"400000","o":"15C18C9"},{"b":"400000","o":"15DE134"},{"b":"400000","o":"16158CB"},{"b":"400000","o":"169E0CE"},{"b":"400000","o":"169E755"},{"b":"400000","o":"169EBCB"},{"b":"400000","o":"1624456"},{"b":"400000","o":"16942DD"},{"b":"400000","o":"165FA4F"},{"b":"400000","o":"165FB5E"},{"b":"400000","o":"1611D2E","s":"wiredtiger_open"},{"b":"400000","o":"C9373F","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKSsS2_S2_mbbb"},{"b":"400000","o":"C8F9F3"},{"b":"400000","o":"BB86C8","s":"_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B2A4E"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B4FC0","s":"_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi"},{"b":"400000","o":"56ADBD","s":"main"},{"b":"7FCFEF851000","o":"21B35","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"400000","o":"5AF377"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.2.12", "gitVersion" : "ef3e1bc78e997f0d9f22f45aeb1d8e3b6ac14a14", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.10.0-514.6.2.el7.x86_64", "version" : "#1 SMP Thu Feb 23 03:04:39 UTC 2017", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "BAAC1A970F6D0F06B88D0DE75BF06E4C260939EC" }, { "b" : "7FFD0E092000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7112DB1E073B211AB0CF8DE793F40F3FF996F5B4" }, { "b" : "7FCFF0B3C000", "path" : "/lib64/libssl.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "90EAF65D9B0EEEB1424241281F7F197451D4317D" }, { "b" : "7FCFF0752000", "path" : "/lib64/libcrypto.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7278C69EE161D98DDD0FA00F92B67AD78C7B7F40" }, { "b" : "7FCFF054A000", "path" : "/lib64/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "82E77ADE22BC9FFF8D3458BD37331E7EDF174C28" }, { "b" : "7FCFF0346000", "path" : "/lib64/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C5F560504E1AF52E29679C3B52FF11121015D6BB" }, { "b" : "7FCFF0044000", "path" : "/lib64/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "721C7CC9488EFA25F83B48AF713AB27DBE48EF3E" }, { "b" : "7FCFEFE2E000", "path" : "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "408B46E291B2D4C9612E27C0509D165D7E186D40" }, { "b" : "7FCFEFC12000", "path" : "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C3DEB1FA27CD0C1C3CC575B944ABACBA0698B0F2" }, { "b" : "7FCFEF851000", "path" : "/lib64/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8B2C421716985B927AA0CAF2A05D0B1F452367F7" }, { "b" : "7FCFF0DAA000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8F3E366E2DB73C330A3791DEAE31AE9579099B44" }, { "b" : "7FCFEF603000", "path" : "/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A2499C359AA179EE23324ED949C0E508E4434F10" }, { "b" : "7FCFEF31C000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E09A34D9083DC6FEAF7018C09D55631DEEE2836D" }, { "b" : "7FCFEF118000", "path" : "/lib64/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BF54B7C8932E450769FBBB8B18864D1DD70BBC67" }, { "b" : "7FCFEEEE6000", "path" : "/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BF8F00D7CB849ADB0B7A4703BC7B8D66AEE6A49C" }, { "b" : "7FCFEECD0000", "path" : "/lib64/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "EA8E45DC8E395CC5E26890470112D97A1F1E0B65" }, { "b" : "7FCFEEAC1000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1E7A92FDD6FB3871DA97F4BCA2E147E72B6B6E1F" }, { "b" : "7FCFEE8BD000", "path" : "/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2E01D5AC08C1280D013AAB96B292AC58BC30A263" }, { "b" : "7FCFEE6A3000", "path" : "/lib64/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FE7AE845A123A3DFC0FDC2408BCBC2BA8B61B158" }, { "b" : "7FCFEE47C000", "path" : "/lib64/libselinux.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "76687CA31A406854DF3BCF8D03055656F56E6892" }, { "b" : "7FCFEE21B000", "path" : "/lib64/libpcre.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AE64AA461A26E01F60408013D361749D56DD0AE1" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x132c032]
 mongod(+0xF2B189) [0x132b189]
 mongod(+0xF2B992) [0x132b992]
 libpthread.so.0(+0xF370) [0x7fcfefc21370]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7fcfef8861d7]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7fcfef8878c8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0x82) [0x12b2312]
 mongod(+0xCAC2A3) [0x10ac2a3]
 mongod(+0x56A1E5) [0x96a1e5]
 mongod(__wt_err+0x8D) [0x96a2ba]
 mongod(__wt_panic+0x24) [0x96a47e]
 mongod(+0x15C00DC) [0x19c00dc]
 mongod(+0x15C0643) [0x19c0643]
 mongod(+0x15BCFC9) [0x19bcfc9]
 mongod(+0x15C18C9) [0x19c18c9]
 mongod(+0x15DE134) [0x19de134]
 mongod(+0x16158CB) [0x1a158cb]
 mongod(+0x169E0CE) [0x1a9e0ce]
 mongod(+0x169E755) [0x1a9e755]
 mongod(+0x169EBCB) [0x1a9ebcb]
 mongod(+0x1624456) [0x1a24456]
 mongod(+0x16942DD) [0x1a942dd]
 mongod(+0x165FA4F) [0x1a5fa4f]
 mongod(+0x165FB5E) [0x1a5fb5e]
 mongod(wiredtiger_open+0x148E) [0x1a11d2e]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKSsS2_S2_mbbb+0x77F) [0x109373f]
 mongod(+0xC8F9F3) [0x108f9f3]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x598) [0xfb86c8]
 mongod(+0x5B2A4E) [0x9b2a4e]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x10) [0x9b4fc0]
 mongod(main+0x15D) [0x96adbd]
 libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF5) [0x7fcfef872b35]
 mongod(+0x5AF377) [0x9af377]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

## repair mongod --dbpath

```
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --repair
2017-03-01T19:00:00.071+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2391 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=CentOS-73-64-minimal
2017-03-01T19:00:00.071+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.12
2017-03-01T19:00:00.071+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ef3e1bc78e997f0d9f22f45aeb1d8e3b6ac14a14
2017-03-01T19:00:00.071+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2017-03-01T19:00:00.071+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-03-01T19:00:00.071+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-03-01T19:00:00.071+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-03-01T19:00:00.071+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2017-03-01T19:00:00.071+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-03-01T19:00:00.071+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-03-01T19:00:00.071+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { repair: true, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo" } }
2017-03-01T19:00:00.089+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongo created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-03-01T19:00:00.089+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected WT journal files.  Running recovery from last checkpoint.
2017-03-01T19:00:00.089+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] journal to nojournal transition config: create,cache_size=18G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-03-01T19:00:00.093+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (0) [1488394800:93588][2391:0x7fc424204dc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: read checksum error for 4096B block at offset 49152: block header checksum of 3921565147 doesn't match expected checksum of 3944682197
2017-03-01T19:00:00.093+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (0) [1488394800:93631][2391:0x7fc424204dc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: WiredTiger.wt: encountered an illegal file format or internal value
2017-03-01T19:00:00.093+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (-31804) [1488394800:93639][2391:0x7fc424204dc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2017-03-01T19:00:00.093+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28558
2017-03-01T19:00:00.093+0000 I -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure


2017-03-01T19:00:00.105+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x132c032 0x132b189 0x132b992 0x7fc422e6c370 0x7fc422ad11d7 0x7fc422ad28c8 0x12b2312 0x10ac2a3 0x96a1e5 0x96a2ba 0x96a47e 0x19c00dc 0x19c0643 0x19bcfc9 0x19c18c9 0x19de134 0x1a158cb 0x1a9e0ce 0x1a9e755 0x1a9ebcb 0x1a24456 0x1a942dd 0x1a5fa4f 0x1a5fb5e 0x1a11d2e 0x1093641 0x108f9f3 0xfb86c8 0x9b2a4e 0x9b4fc0 0x96adbd 0x7fc422abdb35 0x9af377
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"F2C032","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"400000","o":"F2B189"},{"b":"400000","o":"F2B992"},{"b":"7FC422E5D000","o":"F370"},{"b":"7FC422A9C000","o":"351D7","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7FC422A9C000","o":"368C8","s":"abort"},{"b":"400000","o":"EB2312","s":"_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi"},{"b":"400000","o":"CAC2A3"},{"b":"400000","o":"56A1E5"},{"b":"400000","o":"56A2BA","s":"__wt_err"},{"b":"400000","o":"56A47E","s":"__wt_panic"},{"b":"400000","o":"15C00DC"},{"b":"400000","o":"15C0643"},{"b":"400000","o":"15BCFC9"},{"b":"400000","o":"15C18C9"},{"b":"400000","o":"15DE134"},{"b":"400000","o":"16158CB"},{"b":"400000","o":"169E0CE"},{"b":"400000","o":"169E755"},{"b":"400000","o":"169EBCB"},{"b":"400000","o":"1624456"},{"b":"400000","o":"16942DD"},{"b":"400000","o":"165FA4F"},{"b":"400000","o":"165FB5E"},{"b":"400000","o":"1611D2E","s":"wiredtiger_open"},{"b":"400000","o":"C93641","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKSsS2_S2_mbbb"},{"b":"400000","o":"C8F9F3"},{"b":"400000","o":"BB86C8","s":"_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B2A4E"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B4FC0","s":"_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi"},{"b":"400000","o":"56ADBD","s":"main"},{"b":"7FC422A9C000","o":"21B35","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"400000","o":"5AF377"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.2.12", "gitVersion" : "ef3e1bc78e997f0d9f22f45aeb1d8e3b6ac14a14", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.10.0-514.6.2.el7.x86_64", "version" : "#1 SMP Thu Feb 23 03:04:39 UTC 2017", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "BAAC1A970F6D0F06B88D0DE75BF06E4C260939EC" }, { "b" : "7FFD810FB000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7112DB1E073B211AB0CF8DE793F40F3FF996F5B4" }, { "b" : "7FC423D87000", "path" : "/lib64/libssl.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "90EAF65D9B0EEEB1424241281F7F197451D4317D" }, { "b" : "7FC42399D000", "path" : "/lib64/libcrypto.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7278C69EE161D98DDD0FA00F92B67AD78C7B7F40" }, { "b" : "7FC423795000", "path" : "/lib64/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "82E77ADE22BC9FFF8D3458BD37331E7EDF174C28" }, { "b" : "7FC423591000", "path" : "/lib64/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C5F560504E1AF52E29679C3B52FF11121015D6BB" }, { "b" : "7FC42328F000", "path" : "/lib64/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "721C7CC9488EFA25F83B48AF713AB27DBE48EF3E" }, { "b" : "7FC423079000", "path" : "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "408B46E291B2D4C9612E27C0509D165D7E186D40" }, { "b" : "7FC422E5D000", "path" : "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C3DEB1FA27CD0C1C3CC575B944ABACBA0698B0F2" }, { "b" : "7FC422A9C000", "path" : "/lib64/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8B2C421716985B927AA0CAF2A05D0B1F452367F7" }, { "b" : "7FC423FF5000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8F3E366E2DB73C330A3791DEAE31AE9579099B44" }, { "b" : "7FC42284E000", "path" : "/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A2499C359AA179EE23324ED949C0E508E4434F10" }, { "b" : "7FC422567000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E09A34D9083DC6FEAF7018C09D55631DEEE2836D" }, { "b" : "7FC422363000", "path" : "/lib64/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BF54B7C8932E450769FBBB8B18864D1DD70BBC67" }, { "b" : "7FC422131000", "path" : "/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BF8F00D7CB849ADB0B7A4703BC7B8D66AEE6A49C" }, { "b" : "7FC421F1B000", "path" : "/lib64/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "EA8E45DC8E395CC5E26890470112D97A1F1E0B65" }, { "b" : "7FC421D0C000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1E7A92FDD6FB3871DA97F4BCA2E147E72B6B6E1F" }, { "b" : "7FC421B08000", "path" : "/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2E01D5AC08C1280D013AAB96B292AC58BC30A263" }, { "b" : "7FC4218EE000", "path" : "/lib64/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FE7AE845A123A3DFC0FDC2408BCBC2BA8B61B158" }, { "b" : "7FC4216C7000", "path" : "/lib64/libselinux.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "76687CA31A406854DF3BCF8D03055656F56E6892" }, { "b" : "7FC421466000", "path" : "/lib64/libpcre.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AE64AA461A26E01F60408013D361749D56DD0AE1" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x132c032]
 mongod(+0xF2B189) [0x132b189]
 mongod(+0xF2B992) [0x132b992]
 libpthread.so.0(+0xF370) [0x7fc422e6c370]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7fc422ad11d7]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7fc422ad28c8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0x82) [0x12b2312]
 mongod(+0xCAC2A3) [0x10ac2a3]
 mongod(+0x56A1E5) [0x96a1e5]
 mongod(__wt_err+0x8D) [0x96a2ba]
 mongod(__wt_panic+0x24) [0x96a47e]
 mongod(+0x15C00DC) [0x19c00dc]
 mongod(+0x15C0643) [0x19c0643]
 mongod(+0x15BCFC9) [0x19bcfc9]
 mongod(+0x15C18C9) [0x19c18c9]
 mongod(+0x15DE134) [0x19de134]
 mongod(+0x16158CB) [0x1a158cb]
 mongod(+0x169E0CE) [0x1a9e0ce]
 mongod(+0x169E755) [0x1a9e755]
 mongod(+0x169EBCB) [0x1a9ebcb]
 mongod(+0x1624456) [0x1a24456]
 mongod(+0x16942DD) [0x1a942dd]
 mongod(+0x165FA4F) [0x1a5fa4f]
 mongod(+0x165FB5E) [0x1a5fb5e]
 mongod(wiredtiger_open+0x148E) [0x1a11d2e]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKSsS2_S2_mbbb+0x681) [0x1093641]
 mongod(+0xC8F9F3) [0x108f9f3]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x598) [0xfb86c8]
 mongod(+0x5B2A4E) [0x9b2a4e]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x10) [0x9b4fc0]
 mongod(main+0x15D) [0x96adbd]
 libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF5) [0x7fc422abdb35]
 mongod(+0x5AF377) [0x9af377]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
Aborted
```

Comment: what is in /var/log/mongod*.log?

Comment: Thank very much sir for your reply. I have updated the mongod.log in the last part of my question

Comment: try a recover https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/.   looks like a bad bug on improper shutdown... https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26103.  If recover doens't work, Mongo folks seem like can manually recover it for you

Comment: i run mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --repair. but i am still unable to start

Comment: i have updates the -dbpath /var/lib/mongo --repair output in the question

Comment: file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: read checksum error   ... exactly the same as the jira ticket I linked above.  More than likely, MongoDB employees simply went into the WT files and manually fixed the checksum.  They state that they won't tell you how to do that though.